# Converting string date and time to datetime

Tags: php, datetime

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i A', '$info['date']'.' '.'$info['time']');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Basically i'm trying to convert a database time and date to datetime format so i can check things. But I don't think I can actually enter $info['date']/time into the dateTime function so i've no idea what to do. I've looked on this site numerous times and cant seem to find anything.

Comment: Please post the output of `$info['date']` and `$info['time']`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i A', $info['date'].' '.$info['time']);
```

Notice I removed the single quotes around your variables.

Answer (score 3):

Actually following

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i A', '$info['date']'.' '.'$info['time']');
```

Should be:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i A', $info['date'] . ' ' . $info['time']);
```

You have used quotes like `'$info['date']'` but you shouldn't use.

Comment: The white space is required, isn't it?

Comment: He didn't remove the whitespace.

Comment: I meant between the . operator and the operands.

Comment: I didn't remove the white space as `Barmar` already clarified.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick for me

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($YourDateTime));
```

Comment: Where does `$YourDateTime` come from? How does `strtotime` know that the date is d/m/Y, not m/d/Y?